# Sending large dictionary via API call breaks development server

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-rest-framework

I am running a django app with a postgreSQL database and I am trying to send a very large dictionary (consisting of time-series data) to the database.

My goal is to write my data into the DB as fast as possible. I am using the library requests to send the data via an API-call (built with django REST):

My API-view is simple:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def CreateDummy(request):

    for elem, ts in request.data['time_series'] :
        TimeSeries.objects.create(data_json=ts)

    msg = {"detail": "Created successfully"}
    return Response(msg, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

`request.data['time_series']` is a huge dictionary structured like this:

```
{Building1: {1:123, 2: 345, 4:567 .... 31536000: 2345}, .... Building30: {..... }}
```

That means I am having **30 keys with 30 values, whereas the values are each a dict with 31536000 elements.**

My API request looks like this (where data is my dictionary described above):

```
 payload = {
            "time_series": data,
           } 

 requests.request(
        "post", url=endpoint, json=payload
    )
```

The code saves the time-series data to a jsonb-field in the backend. Now that works if I only loop over the first 4 elements of the dictionary. I can get that data in in about 1minute. But when I loop over the whole dict, my development server shuts down. I guess it's because the memory is insufficient. I get a `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`. Is the whole dict saved to memory before it starts iterating? I doubt it because I read that in python3 looping with `.items()` returns an iterator and is the preferred way to do this.

Is there a better way to deal with massive dicts in django/python? Should I loop through half of it and then through the other half? Or is there a faster way? Maybe using `pandas`? Or maybe sending the data differently? I guess I am looking for the most performant way to do this.

Happy to provide more code if needed.

Any help, hints or guides are very much appreciated! Thanks in advance

EDIT2: I think it is not my RAM usage or the size of the dict. I still have 5GiB of RAM left when the server shuts down. ~~And the size of the dict is 1176bytes~~ *Dict is much larger, see comments*

EDIT3: I can't even print the huge dict. It also shuts down then

EDIT4: When split the data up and send it not all at once the server can handle it. But when I try to query it back the server breaks again. It breaks on my production server (nginx AWS RDS setup) and it breaks on my local dev server. I am pretty sure it's because django can't handle queries that big with my current setup. But how could I solve this?

EDIT5: So what I am looking for is a two part solution. One for the creation of the data and one for the querying of the data. The creation of the data I described above. But even if I get all that data into the database, I will still have problems getting it out again.

I tried this by creating the data not all together but every time-series on its own. So let's assume I have this huge data in my DB and I try to query it back. All time-series objects belong to a network so I tried this like so:

```
class TimeSeriesByTypeAndCreationMethod(ListAPIView):
    """Query time-series in specific network."""

    serializer_class = TimeSeriesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Query time-series

        Query by name of network, type of data, creation method and
        source.
        """

        network = self.kwargs["name_network"]

        if TimeSeries.objects.filter(
            network_element__network__name=network,
        ).exists():
            time_series = TimeSeries.objects.filter(
                network_element__network__name=network,
            )
            return time_series
        else:
            raise NotFound()
```

But the query breaks the server like the data creation before. I think also this is too much data load. I thought I could use raw sql avoid breaking the server... Or is there also a better way?

EDIT6: Relevant models:

```
class TimeSeries(models.Model):

    TYPE_DATA_CHOICES = [
        ....many choices...
    ]

    CREATION_METHOD_CHOICES = [
        ....many choices...
    ]

    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    network_element = models.ForeignKey(
        Building,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    type_data = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=30,
        choices=TYPE_DATA_CHOICES,
    )

    creation_method = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=30,
        choices=CREATION_METHOD_CHOICES,
    )

    source = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=300
    )

    data_json = JSONField(
        help_text="Data for time series in JSON format. Valid JSON expected."
    )

    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.creation_method}:{self.type_data}"



class Building(models.Model):

    USAGE_CHOICES = [
        ...
    ]

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    street = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    house_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    zip_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    city = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    usage = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        choices=USAGE_CHOICES,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    .....many more fields....
```

Comment: Is Ngnix(or similar server) terminating the request?

Comment: Thanks Arakkal! My devlopment server runs in a docker environment and there is no nginx. I will post the setup. So there is little I can tweak I think. (In production, yes I have nginx running)

Comment: Try using [bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) :) hope this will help

Comment: Ah yes I will try this, thank you! This will only hit the DB once right? But it will take extra time to restructure the data into a list

Comment: Or can I `bulk_create` with a dict too?

Comment: Your dict cannot be 1176 bytes, since it contains 946 million entries (30 keys * 31,536,000). Just a single dict with 31,536,000 elements is 1.25 GB. Every time a dict runs out of space it doubles its memory. A dict with 22,300,000 entries takes up 0.625 GB, but 22,400,000 entries jumps to 1.25 GB. 


>>> print(sys.getsizeof({x: x for x in range(31536000)}) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0, "GB")

Comment: Ok thanks, I hear you! I printed that with `sys.getsizeof(request.data["time_series"])` and that's what showed up. Will run another test... But is a dict then a bad datastructure for this use-case if it doubles its memory?

Comment: I think you can send the data as a *file* to the Django, in a *chunked fashion*. Then on the server-side, you can process the ***chunks*** (somehow) and can write it to the database. (FYI: I am not sure about the technical feasibility of my suggestion)

Comment: Thanks Arakkal! If I had that working it would solve the writing part. But also the querying this data back breaks my server.

Comment: An obvious solution (which you already mentioned) is to send the data in chunks of json small enough that your server can handle.  Is there a particular reason why you need to send all the data at once?

Comment: Is there an error message output to the dev-server's log?  It's almost certainly an OOM issue, but the log output might confirm it.

Comment: n+1 query, no pagination and no indexes on dbfor efficient lookups. Please add relevant models for advice on proper indexing

Comment: @pygeek I added the relevant models. I never used indexing before, so I'd very much appreciate your input on this

Comment: @Elrond Supports Monica yes, speed. I sent it in chunks before, doing 33 requests. But this was very slow. So I figured only having one single request would be more performant. I am not sure if that holds true though, what do you think?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I don't think I have a server log for the dev server, but let me double-check that.... The server just throws an `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`

Comment: Try to paginate query set retrieval, add attribute db_index=True on relative foreign keys fields "not all of it" in your model, start with your local machine and test without Django REST framework see if it will work! check live server logs for better understanding about the error.
- auto_now is enough alone, remove null and blank attributes.
- foreign_key can not be null or blank for your model relation not to break.
- make sure that all choices have unique keys.
you have to break the problem into pieces to be able to solve it @micromegas

Comment: @AhmedShehab thank you again. I paginated now the queryset and if  limit it to 1 object the server does not break anymore. But then I only have the data of 1 object... Is the idea to then make requests to every paginated page? Or how else would I retrieve all the data from every paginated page? Also I was wondering if it would be a good idea to write the data to a CSV file on the server and return the CSV file... What do you think?

Comment: @Micromegas in regards to pagination, DRF returns a nice object with results and count and pages, examine the returned object.
Regarding using CSV I would say you are the only one who can see the full picture, however it will be painful later to maintain if you want generate a report or truncate some columns and if you split the DB into different engines this way you are giving away a lot of Postgres perks. 
- how about making use of the browser cache and IndexedDB.
- If the query time for DB is a bottle neck, try NoSQL data stores like Redis, use Uwsgi and Ngnix.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your issues using two techniques.

### Data Creation

Use bulk_create to insert a large number of records, if SQL error happens due to large query size etc then provide the `batch_size` in `bulk_create`.

```
records = []
for elem, ts in request.data['time_series'] :
    records.append(
         TimeSeries(data_json=ts)
    )

# setting batch size t 1000

TimeSeries.objects.bulk_create(records, batch_size=1000)
```

There're some caveats with bulk_create like it will not generate signals and others see more in [Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

### Data Retrieval

Configure rest framework to use pagination **default configuration**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

For custom configuration use

```
class TimeSeriesResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 50
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 10000

class BillingRecordsView(generics.ListAPIView):
   serializer_class = TimeSeriesSerializer
   pagination_class = TimeSeriesResultsSetPagination


   def get_queryset(self):
    """Query time-series

    Query by name of network, type of data, creation method and
    source.
    """

    network = self.kwargs["name_network"]

    if TimeSeries.objects.filter(
        network_element__network__name=network,
    ).exists():
        time_series = TimeSeries.objects.filter(
            network_element__network__name=network,
        )
        return time_series
    else:
        raise NotFound()
```

See other techniques for pagination at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Comment: thank you sonus21 and sorry for the late reply. Let me try this and report back!

Answer (score 1):

@micromegas when your solution is correct theoretically, however calling create() many times in a loop, I believe that causes the ConnectionError exception.

try to refactor to something like:

```
big_data_holder = []
for elem, ts in request.data['time_series'] :
    big_data_holder.append(
         TimeSeries(data_json=ts)
    )

# examine the structure 
print(big_data_holder) 

TimeSeries.objects.bulk_create(big_data_holder)
```

please check for some downsides for this method
[Django Docs bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Comment: Thank you I will try this now and report back. This would solve the creation part. It would still break my server when I query that data back I think

Comment: Provide a code example and what do you want to achieve and I will try to the best to help. Normally when we query DB we try to limit the search by pk or specific column, while Postgres has wide variety of string search.

**Personal advise:** try to make it as light as possible, split chunks considering connection speed limitation and if not really possible you got to consider concurrency.

Comment: Thanks so much. I edited the question (Edit5). I would have posted a separate question but I think it is in fact the same problem. Getting the data in and getting the data out both breaks the server. Do you think I should use raw SQL and lookup by primary key instead of the network name? And how could I split a query into chunks or make it more performant? Thanks again

Comment: Now after those tries you might want to re-engineer the model itself.can't get the full picture but as you say even after paginating and splitting still breaks, Handle exceptions to know what error has thrown with try except blocks " you will have better error reporting". 
**Here are some thoughts:**
- Separate DB for writing and reading
- Separate DB for lookups only with relational key or two  to the main large DB with caching and post changes only when there is a change.
- Go Async and let it takes its time "check django and gevent" to handle concurrency. "I would recommend this"

Comment: BTW try to greater Postgres timeout, here is a nice answer:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/is-it-possible-to-limit-timeout-on-postgres-server#answer-164450

Comment: use db indexes and pagination to optimize lookups. Also, use async route with background workers and if necessary increase db resources. Increasing timeout should be last resort as this alone isn’t scalable.

Comment: @pygeek I will look this up but atm I am not sure how I could use async route with background workers....